# iOS Alamofire : read cookie before autoredirect

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a POST method that on success redirects me on another page. In the final destination as result I have no set Cookies. How to retrieve cookies from first response? (Alamofire does autoredirect)

```
Alamofire.request( NSLocalizedString("url_login", comment: ""), method: .post, parameters: params).response{ response in          
          if let headerFields = response.response?.allHeaderFields as? [String: String],
           let URL = response.request?.url
            {
                let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: headerFields, for: URL)
                print(cookies)
            }
            if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
               /.../
                }else{
                    /..../
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just disable redirect and read the results.
like this:

`delegate.taskWillPerformHTTPRedirection = { _, _, _, _ in
            return nil
        }`

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/491cf2f2557379d212eca2ed3e62f01a50c8c1b4/Tests/SessionDelegateTests.swift